# The conflict of separated title and figure

Tags: floats, landscape

My title and figure are separated even though there is enough space on the page. How can I solve this problem?

[image]

My code is:

```
\begin{document}

\usepackage {landscape}
The
\usepackage {graphicx}

\begin{landscape}

\chapter{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}

\begin{figure}[p]

\includegraphics[width=50mm,scale=1.5]{AP2.png}

\end{figure}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just don't use `figure`, but `center` or `flushleft`.

Answer (score 3):

With `[p]` you tell latex that the figure should be placed on a separate *page*. With something like `[htbp]` it will first test if the figure can be placed *here*.

`land­scape` is long su­per­seded. I used the `lscape` package instead.

```
\documentclass{report}

\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

    \chapter{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}

    \begin{table}[htbp]
        \includegraphics[width=.6\textwidth]{example-image-16x9}
    \end{table}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I'd say it's simpler *not* to use `figure`.

Comment: I used your code but the problem continues. They are in seperated pages.

Comment: @egreg Probably true, but I don't know enough details from the real document. From the image in the question, I'd say it should be `table`....

Comment: @ZeynepP As Bernhard already explained to you: then your image is too big!

Answer (score 1):

You want to use neither `figure` nor `table`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}

\section{TOTAL ACHIEVEMENT SCORES IN QUESTIONNAIRE}

\vspace{\fill}

\begin{flushleft}
\includegraphics[height=.7\textheight]{example-image}
\end{flushleft}

\vspace*{\fill}

\end{landscape}

\end{document}
```

I used `article` because your class is unspecified and uses nonstandard chapter headings, but the idea would be the same. Adjust the dimension to suit, but remember that using both `width` and `scale` is not a good idea: better `width` or `height`.

[image]